# Is post Notification occupy memory?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsnotificationcenter

In my code i add observer of post Notification in viewDidLoad method.
Now when view controller want's to load at that time it is check for the post Notification methods.
So is it occupy the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea about memory consumption, but it's a best practice to remove observer of post notification in dealloc of the same view controller.

Comment: Yes i remove observer in the dealloc method. But my question is that it occupy's memory for run time the application.